# WP8 WebBrowser control not always showing content

Tags: webbrowser-control, windows-phone

If you remove the WebBrowser control from its actual parent and add it to another container a few times, the loaded page in the webBrowser may not be shown.

I made a small Windows Phone solution where it is easily reproducible:
[WindowsPhoneSolution.zip](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0BzJ70QNGyq-fcnVzeGZIMW9OUWc/edit?usp=sharing)

You must press on the upper button a few times and at some point you will see that both WebBrowsers stay blank
(Note: reproducible only in the Emulator WVGA 512MB ! Maybe because my test device is faster? I don't know if it's an Emulator or System Bug)

What I tried so far?

1. Calling methods with names like refresh, invalidate, etc. on the browser container and the browser control itself
2. Changing the size of WebBrowser control after switching containers
3. The only way I could find out to force the content to appear in the case it didn't was using a separate button and when clicking it changing the size of the WebBrowser control (note: the new size should be different to the orginal one). This made the content of the WebBrowser to appear.

Comment: There is something inherently wrong with the approach you are taking. First of all, when you are using the first assignment, you are **not creating an object copy**. What scenario are you trying to cover?

Comment: Scenario: cache the WebBrowser content to avoid reloading the same site

Comment: Questions is - what do you gain by doing this instead of relying on what the OS already does?

Comment: I don#t understand you, what is the OS already doing? From my point of view if the WebBrowser is not always showing the content then it is something that should be fixed.

Comment: In normal conditions, you shouldn't touch the WebBrowser control at all in terms of content reload on application resume/start. That is, you don't need to worry about "caching" it.

Comment: I never spoke about resume/start. Sorry, but you are not helping with your comments, if you don't know the answer then you don't.

Comment: I don't see why you need to cache the browser content when the OS already does that for you when necessary.